# Clicking on a movieclip inside another movieclip on AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Alright, what i need it's simple but its driving me crazy, i want to know if AS3 detects my mouse inside a movieclip.
For example, i have a movieclip instanced "BEframes" which is inside movieclip "BE1" and i want to put him inside a new movieclip instanced "roll". So the order would be roll > BE1 > BEframes.
I want to know if flash will only detect "roll" or he will detect all movieclips, thank you,

```
for(i=1;i<=77;i++){
    var str:String =("BE" + i);
    this[str].BEframes.gotoAndStop(i);
    this[str].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clique);
    this[str].addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, over);
    this[str].addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, out);
    }
function clique(evt:MouseEvent):void{
    var botao:String = evt.currentTarget.name.toString();
    var num:String = botao.replace("BE", "");
    parede_esquerda.gotoAndStop(num);
}
function out(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    evt.currentTarget.gotoAndPlay("out");
}`enter code here`
function over(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    evt.currentTarget.gotoAndPlay("over");
}
```

*

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you should use MOUSE_OVER and MOUSE_OUT instead of ROLL_OVER and ROLL_OUT.

```
this[str].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, over);
this[str].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, out);
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid receiving mouseEvent for movieClips set [mouseEnabled](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#mouseEnabled) to false, i.e if you don't want clip roll's mouse event set`roll.mouseEnabled = false` so that the object below will receive mouseEvent